# ReactJS cache components depending on property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm working on a component which shows data depending on a selected list-group-item.
The selected item (or type) is stored in the component's state.

The problem I am facing is, that a 3rd-party component (which depends on the type) loads the data inside the `componentDidMount` lifecycle call.

The `render` of my component looks something like this:

```
{(() => {
    if (this.componentCache[selectedType] == null) {
        switch (selectedType) {
            case Type1:
                this.componentCache[selectedType] = <ThirdPartyComponent type={selectedType} />;
                break;
            case Type2:
                this.componentCache[selectedType] = <ThirdPartyComponent type={selectedType} />;
                break;
            case Type3:
                this.componentCache[selectedType] = <ThirdPartyComponent type={selectedType} />;
                break;
            case Type4:
                this.componentCache[selectedType] = <ThirdPartyComponent type={selectedType} />;
                break;
            default:
                throw new RangeError(`The type ${selectedType} is not known or not implemented`);
        }
    }

    return this.componentCache[selectedType];
})()}
```

If the `selectedType` changes, `React` sees the component as already mounted and will not call the `componentDidMount` lifecycle. Therefore no new data is loaded.

I tried to cache the components in `private readonly componentCache: {[type:string]:JSX.Element}` but still the same.
Another try was to add a unique `key` property. But then it always calls the `componentDidMount` which is not what I want to.

How can I store/cache those components so they get only loaded once per `selectedType`?

Comment: Does you ThirdPartyComponent make requests to server?

Comment: Yes. It loads the data to be shown in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle call